# progressbar won't update with backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

im making file transfer (Server-Client) TCP
i've already looked for same questions like this one .. but no answer worked for me ..

ProgressBar doesn't update with backgroundworker .. i've searched for tutorials to do this .. and i exactly followed the steps.
the form lags while sending and after the file sent.. the progressbar goes to 100%

The file sent succesfully the send method code works fine... my problem just with updating the progressbar .. how do i fix that ??

Here i call (**backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync**)

```
public void Send(string destPath)
    {
        if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            List<String> job = new List<string>();
            job.Add(listView1.Items[0].ToolTipText);
            job.Add(destPath);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(job);
        }
    }
```

**DoWork Method**

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> job = (List<string>)e.Argument;
        SendFile(job[0],job[1]);
    }
```

here's the SEND method which i use (**backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress**)

```
private void SendFile(string srcPath, string destPath)
    {
        string dest = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(srcPath));
        using (fs = new FileStream(srcPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            try
            {
                long fileSize = fs.Length;
                sizeAll = fileSize;
                long sum = 0;
                int count = 0;
                data = new byte[fs.Length];
                SendCommand("receive<" + dest + "<" + fs.Length.ToString());
                while (sum < fileSize)
                {
                    if (fileSize - sum < packetSize)
                    {
                        count = fs.Read(data, 0, (int)(fileSize - sum));
                        network.Write(data, 0, (int)(fileSize - sum));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count = fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        network.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                    fs.Seek(sum, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    sum += count;
                    sumAll += count;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((sum * 100) / fileSize));
                }
                network.Flush();
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseTransfer();
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is **backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged**

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBarFile.Value= e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Comment: Does the progresschanged method get called? If so, what does the callstack look like?

Comment: Are you sure that transfered files are the same? Because fs.Seek seems off to me; it returns to 0 offset after the first pass and rereads first packetSize of data in second pass. I don't think you need to Seek anyway because file reader will remain at first position after last read byte.

Comment: Instead of data = new byte[fs.Length]; write data = new byte[packetSize]; and remove fs.Seek. I believe that progress bar will work. The only reason file transfer works is because it is read and sent in one packet.

Comment: thanks man.. i've fixed it.. the code is correct .. just the packetsize thing .. should i delete my question ??

Comment: I am a newbie here so i don't really know but I think you should not delete questions as other people may learn from your mistakes ;-) And be sure to remove fs.Seek because it will corrupt your files.

Comment: One other thing - if someone left you a message under your question and you want to respond, be sure to start your comment with @ followed by at least three characters of persons name. Stack Overflow will then send this person a notification and you will get a quicker response. I came here again out of curiosity, but this will not always be the case. Cheers.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović about fs.Seek .. u may have a revision about it .. because it the most important line in the code .. it lets me send large files like 7G.B .. the send method works great im using it to send files .. just the line (byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];) should be [packetSize] . that little mistake made this question. everything else works fine and tested.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not reading this right. To my knowledge Seek positions read/write pointer in stream. You should not touch it as you read from stream sequentially. After the first pass you reset it to zero (sum = 0 at this point) and you read the first packetSize of bytes again duplication the output. The file size remains the same, but data is garbled. Just to ease my mind, did you compare files contents?

Comment: sure .. sent a video and i watched .. i sent a txt file and compared..
fs.Seek .. let the fs.Read to read from sum position .. so i can read 8kb .. send them .. seek to sum position and so on .. if i didn't do that i would have to read the whole file in ram and send it 8kb by 8kb .. and that's not good if i wanted to send a large file.

Comment: Ok then, happy programming :-)

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović .. i have noticed something about your note .. so i asked this question .. check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558914/sent-file-has-some-corrupted-data-tcp-sockets-how-to-fix-it

Comment: Seek does not do what you think. It is used to reposition read or write pointer inside a file. You read data in small packages and this allows you to transfer files that would not fit into memory. You can safely delete this line.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović after i tried removing seek .. the sent file got really corrupted more than with seek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for [Nikola Markovinović] his answer was:

the line that causes the error was :

```
data = new byte[fs.Length];
```

after correcting the code :

```
data = new byte[packetSize];  
while (sum < fileSize)
{
     count = fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
     network.Write(data, 0, count);
     sum += count;
     backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((sum * 100) / fileSize));
 }
 network.Flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems strange the you're able to assign a value to the a `UI` control from another thread without getting any exception. Or *that* is, may be, a *real* issue. 
Like a first thing I would do, if the code of `ProgressChanged` is inside (say) `WindowsForm` class, write like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, 
                                                 ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(()=>
        progressBarFile.Value= e.ProgressPercentage;
    ));
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: The `BackgroundWorker` automatically calls the `ProgressChanged` handler on the UI thread.

Comment: i've read that backgroundworker.reportprogress update the progressbar from UI thread .. it works when i used the tutorial.. just didn't work in my code

Answer (score 1):

Did you set?

```
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

(Either in code or in the properties window)

---

EDIT:

Shouldn't you be reading like this

```
count = fs.Read(data, 0, packetSize);
```

instead of reading `data.Length` bytes? Since you set `data = new byte[fs.Length]` the file will be read all at once, instead of in little pieces, which is required in order to see the progress bar change progressively.

Answer (score 0):

The background worker is dorking around on a new thread, therefore, calling anything back to the original form and its controls (or original thread) will require some delegation to accomplish what you desire.  I have several code examples that I can share but they would take up far too much space here on this site.  As a quick assistance, try some of this information from this site.

[Background Worker with Delegates](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/83b39281-7378-44cd-bdef-9ac1d899ba06/)

Of course, you can always Google for more regarding threading, delegates, etc.  I hope that helps.

Comment: i've read that backgroundworker.reportprogress update the progressbar from UI thread .. it works when i used the tutorial.. just didn't work in my code

Comment: It can get quite interesting.  I tend to avoid the BackgroundWorker class and just go with boring multi-threading.  Additionally, check out [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2083/The-key-to-multi-threaded-Windows-Forms-UI-interac).  Many of the principles remain the same regardless.

Comment: i think this could be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Well it may be something quirky but always worth checking the steps its easy to overlook first:

1. Have you set WorkerReportsProgress on the BackgroundWorker to true?
2. Have you hooked up the ProgressChanged event to your event handler?

Finally just compare your solution to a sample at the link below - it may remind you of something you've forgotten to do:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: 1 . yea its true.
2 . its hooked because i added it as a tool from toolbox + when the file sent progress goes to 100%

finally i've already checked that link before and it worked when i use it but didn't work with my code