# Sent file has some corrupted data TCP sockets .. how to fix it?

Tags: c#, file-transfer, corrupt

I have problem with my transfer files application .. everything looks great and works the way it should be .. but then I discovered that some pieces of the sent file is corrupted.

 Like when I send a video file (.MP4) it sent successfully but when I play it some frames of it got corrupted like in the  snapshot picture .. I played the source Mp4 file and the picture was so perfect and never looked like in that snapshot picture.
So here's my code ..  I'm confused now about using `fs.Seek` .. someone told me it doesn't make the new file the same as the source file.

**I'm using SOCKETS TCP .. (.Net 4.0)**

[image]

**Send method (CLIENT):**

```
FileStream fs;
long sum;
long fileSize;
byte[] data = null;
NetworkStream network; 
const int packetSize = 1024*8;

private void SendFile(string srcPath, string destPath)
    {
        string dest = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(srcPath));
        using (fs = new FileStream(srcPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            try
            {
                sum = 0;
                int count = 0;
                data = new byte[packetSize];
                //send the destination path and the file size to SERVER.
                SendCommand("receive<" + dest + "<" + fs.Length.ToString());
                while (sum < fileSize)
                {
                    if (fileSize - sum < packetSize)
                    {
                        count = fs.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileSize - sum));
                        network.Write(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileSize - sum));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count = fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        network.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                    fs.Seek(sum, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    sum += count;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((sum * 100) / fileSize));
                }
                network.Flush();
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Dispose();
                data = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Receive method (SERVER):**

```
FileStream fs;
long sum;
long fileSize;
byte[] data = null;
NetworkStream network; 
const int packetSize = 1024*8;

public void Receive(string destPath, long fileSize)
    {
        using (fs = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            try
            {
                int count = 0;
                long sum = 0;
                data = new byte[packetSize];
                while (sum < fileSize)
                {
                    if (fileSize - sum < packetSize)
                    {
                        count = network.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileSize - sum));
                        fs.Write(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileSize - sum));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count = network.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                    fs.Seek(sum, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    sum += count;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Dispose();
                data = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you seeking on `fs`? It should already be in the right position for the next read.

Comment: it didn't work with out the SEEK .. i've tried to remove that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you didn't solve it by now, I propose this code. Put it inside                 while (sum < fileSize).

Send:

```
    count = fs.Read(data, 0, packetSize);
    network.Write(data, 0, count);
    sum += count;
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((sum * 100) / fileSize));
```

and Receive:

```
    count = network.Read(data, 0, packetSize);
    fs.Write(data, 0, count);
    sum += count;
```

This will ensure that you transfer just the data you have read. Notice that you do not need **if** part because Read will return number of bytes read, so it doesn't matter if you are at beginning or at end of the file, Read will read all it can up to limit you provided as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You never take into consideration how many bytes you read from file or network stream. See your `count` variables in your server & client codes.

You should write `count` bytes to other stream after reading from input stream.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample from your code in `Receive`

```
count = network.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

How can you be sure that you have read `data.Length` bytes

Comment: ummm and why should i do that ?

Comment: Because `stream.Read(buffer,0,1000)` doesn't mean you will get 1000 bytes from stream. It can be anything between 0 & 1000. This is why `Read` returns how many bytes it read.

Comment: umm .. would you edit my code and post an answer, because i dont know what should i edit exactly

Answer (score 0):

After countless hours of research I found the answer.

See...when you write synchronously or asynchronously (especially asynchronously) chunks of binaries that compose a larger file size than, let's say 8000 bytes the binaries can lag behind in a stream and be assembled in the receiving end incorrectly. The solution for this is to wrap the socket object in a NetworkStream and to send the data to the receiving end byte by byte.

I will hear angry nerds telling me that it is inefficient to do this but it is the only way for files to be transferred correctly.

The solution?

Implement a hybrid system for text and files, if you need to send both.

The data transmission end method:

```
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

client.Connect()

NetworkStream network_data_stream = new NetworkStream(client);


///////////////////////////////////
// Text information transmission //
///////////////////////////////////

byte[] text_info = new byte[TEXT_INFO_SIZE];

network_data_stream .Write(text_info, 0, text_info.Lenght);

///////////////////////////////////////////







///////////////////////////////////
// File information transmission //
///////////////////////////////////


List<byte> file_info = List<byte>();


for(int Index = 0; Index <= file_info.Lenght - 1; Index++)
{
   network_data_stream.WriteByte((byte) file_info[Index]);
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The receiving end method:

```
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
server.Listen(3000);

Socket client = server.Accept();

NetworkStream network_data_stream = new NetworkStream(client);


///////////////////////////////////
// Text information transmission //
///////////////////////////////////

byte[] text_info = new byte[TEXT_INFO_SIZE];

network_data_stream .Read(text_info, 0, text_info.Lenght);

///////////////////////////////////////////







///////////////////////////////////
// File information transmission //
///////////////////////////////////


List<byte> file_info = List<byte>();


for(int Index = 0; Index <= file_info.Lenght - 1; Index++)
{
   network_data_stream.ReadByte((byte) file_info[Index]);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

```
//////////////////////
// ! ! ! NOTE ! ! ! //
//////////////////////

/*
You will need to modify this methods in order to send the file size to the receiving end before sending the file, in order to set a fixed buffer size for the file.


You can use the WriteAsync method instead of the Write method for text information transmission in order to improve performance, without any binary fragmentation cost if the data to be transmitted is lower than 8000 bytes.


If the text information to be sent is greater than 8000 bytes, the recommended method is to use the byte by byte information transmission method. This method can be used inside SslStream.

*/
```